# Can't insert Opportunity record with an AccountId

Tags: apex

I've simplified the issue in code below. I run the code as anonymous user in Developer Console.

- I am testing in the Partial sandbox
- The code runs fine if I do not set the AccountId.
- The code fails when I set the AccountId (the AccountId I am using is valid).

The error is:
*System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id: []*

CODE:

```
Opportunity NewOpp = new Opportunity();

NewOpp.Closedate= System.today();
NewOpp.Name = 'XXX';
NewOpp.StageName = '10R-Renewal';
NewOpp.LeadSource = 'Other - None';

//Use any valid AccountId in Partial Sandbox and it FAILS. 
//If I remove this line, it works. 
//I need to know how to include AccountID when inserting a new Opp.
NewOpp.AccountId = '001410000210acdAAA'; 

insert NewOpp;
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: try to query the specific account record using the query like below

`Account acc = [Select id, name from Account where id = '001410000210acdAAA'];`

Now try to pass this id to the opporttunity like below :-

`NewOpp.AccountId = acc.id;`

Comment: what is your OWD for Account?  If private, does the anon user have access to that Account. You should also look at the debug log to see if there is some downstream automation that is failing due to the presence of the Opportunity.AccountId

Comment: Good thought but I checked and the OWD is not private. I checked the log and it give the same error as above. The next line is a Fatal error as follows: 
15:14:13:000 FATAL_ERROR AnonymousBlock: line 13, column 1